# Arduino - Optimising existing method for iterating through an array

Tags: arrays, loops, arduino

Is there a more efficient and cleaner way of doing what the following method is already doing?

```
void sendCode(prog_uint16_t inArray[], int nLimit) {

  unsigned int arr[nLimit];
  unsigned int c;
  int index = 0;

  while ((c = pgm_read_word(inArray++))) {
    arr[index] = c;
    index++;
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < nLimit; i=i+2) {
    delayMicroseconds(arr[i]);
    pulseIR(arr[i+1]);
  }

}
```

This is in reference to an existing question I had answered.

[Arduino - Iterate through C array efficiently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8939937/arduino-iterate-through-c-array-efficiently/8951798#8951798)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be no need for the local `arr` array variable. If you do away with that you should both save temporary stack space and speed up execution by removing the need to copy data.

```
void sendCode(const prog_uint16_t inArray[]) {
  unsigned int c;

  for (int i = 0; c = pgm_read_word(inArray++); i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 0) { // Even array elements are delays
      delayMicroseconds(c);
    } else {          // Odd array elements are pulse lengths
      pulseIR(c);
    }
  }
}
```

This code assumes that the maximum integer stored in an `int` is greater than the maximum size of `inArray` (this seems reasonable as the original code essentially makes the same assumption by using an `int` for `nLimit`).

Comment: Thanks for that, looks like it's working fine. It saves space as I can remove the `nLimit` that's passed to each method. The only modification I had to make was that `sendCode()` should take `const prog_uint16_t inArray[]`.